# How do I correctly use .OrderBy() in this scenario

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have the interface

```
   public interface IStoreItem
    {

        decimal Price { get; }
    }
```

And the class which implements it.

```
public class ProductShell : IStoreItem
    {

        EFDbContext repository = new EFDbContext();


        public int ShellID { get; set; }
        public bool? Published { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get { return repository.ShellMembers.Where(x => x.ShellID == ShellID).Select(x => x.Product.ListPrice).Sum();  } }

    }
```

The price is set correctly, however when I attempt to do an OrderBy by ascending (default)  I do not see any changes in the list and items remain in their old positions. Being ProductShell objects where the Price property is set are still being ordered from highest to lowest and not vice versa.

```
            List<IStoreItem> StoreItems = new List<IStoreItem>();

            StoreItems.AddRange(repository.ProductShells.Where(x => x.Published != null));

            StoreItems.OrderBy(x => x.Price);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.OrderBy` creates a new sequence. You should use [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) here. Or sort it before adding to the list:

```
List<IStoreItem> StoreItems = repository.ProductShells
     .Where(x => x.Published != null)
     .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
     .ToList<IStoreItem>();
```

Comment: Thanks.. Something like this also works quite well: StoreItems = StoreItems.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList(); I have objects of different types that implement the interface in that list, so I need to sort after everything's added.